# Outlook Add in How to Get multiple locations in appointment am more metadata

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, office-js, office-addins

I am using JavaScript api for outlook add in. I want to get the location of a meeting. How do i get this

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.location.getAsync(
            function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                    write(asyncResult.error.message);
                }
                else {
                    // Successfully got the location, display it.
                    console.log('The location is: ' , asyncResult);
                }
            });
```

This gives me the first location in the list and only the string representation of the location.

1. Can I get more metadata on the location?
2. How do I get all the locations in the location field for the Appointment?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, location.getAsync does not currently support multiple locations. This is something we will address in the future.

To answer your two questions, we suggest [using REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api) to retrieve the locations as well as their metadata. Particularly, this [event API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_get).

Note: This will only retrieve locations that are already saved to the server. If the appointment is being composed or edited, this will not retrieve the newly updated locations until the form is synced to the server.

Comment: So in other words if the appointment is being composed, there is currently no way of getting more information from the selected locations (rooms) ? All I can get is the room name?

Comment: In that case follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100304/get-event-calendar-id-from-within-meeting-request-item-context